# Eddy currents add in electromagnetically damped pendulum experiment?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, electromagnetic-induction

I have conducted a pendulum experiment. A rectangular magnet attached to the end of a compound pendulum swings beside a bunch of thin 1mm thick aluminium sheets (I was unable to obtain aluminium sheets of different thicknesses, so I had to stack them). I changed the distance and number of sheets used.

I know that the magnetic field lines penetrate the aluminium sheets, but I am unsure whether the effect is simply additive, because each sheet which the magnetic field penetrates have their own eddy current? I have tried to find an explanation about how the size -- or the strength of the eddy currents -- are affected by the size of the conductor through which they flow.

A similar question which may elucidate this question: [Do eddy currents flow through the depth of sheets of conductors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/723768/do-eddy-currents-flow-through-the-depth-of-sheets-of-conductors)

Comment: " changing the angle for oscillations to increase velocity of the pendulum."  $v=\sqrt{2L*(1-\cos(\phi))}$ for the maximum speed.

Comment: @trula ahh thanks! That is helpful. Do you have any ideas as to how exactly to experimentally keep the angle of oscillations constant? I am thinking of a compound pendulum, which will allow me to do this more easily, because a string is very unstable and unpredictable.

Comment: To Studie the effect of the eddy current, the angle has to decrease with time, so why do you want to keep it constant? First measuring without the sheets and then with the sheets present should give you the influence you seek.the first experiment also give you the moment of inertia .

Comment: @trula Sorry, I was referring to the initial angles constant. Since the eddy current strength is directly related to velocity at which the magnet is moving across the conductor (speed at which magnetic flux is changing), the initial angle of the release would increase the maximum velocity as the pendulum passes through the equilibrium point. I am trying to find a way to vary velocities of the pendulum and record the effect of initial angle (which affects maximum velocity) on the total time period of damping.